# htaccess redirect 301 parent url only

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am using clean urls on my website. I have changed the path of one of the pages. The original path is:

```
mywebsite.com/projects
```

and the new path is:

```
mywebsite.com/what-we-do
```

I tried adding a 301 redirect as follows:

```
Redirect 301 /projects /what-we-do
```

However, this works for that page, but it also means all child pages beginning `/projects/xxx` are getting forwarded to `/what-we-do/xxx` which I don't want to happen. I want the projects child pages not to redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `RedirectMatch` instead of `Redirect`.

That uses a regular expression and allows you to specify an exact match.

```
RedirectMatch 301 /projects$ /what-we-do
```

(`$` being regex for "the end").